# With JPA, is it possible to map relational tables to java.util.Map as @Entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

### About the question

First time I ask question here, so I'm trying to be clear about my question. I'm **not** asking how to map relationships using `java.util.Map`, nor to use `java.util.Map` as an `@Embedded` object. What I really want to know is the possibility of using `java.util.Map` as the mapped `@Entity`.

Samples are always better than thousands of words. Here is what I want in short:

```
<entity class="java.util.HashMap" access="KEY">
    <table name="TABLE_1"/>
    <attributes>
        <id name="id">
            <column name="COL_ID" />
        </id>
        <basic name="attr1" >
            <column name="COL_1" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="attr2" >
            <column name="COL_2" />
            <temporal>DATE</temporal>
        </basic>
        ...
    </attributes>
</entity>
```

As described above, the content of relational table `TABLE_1` is mapped to class `java.util.HashMap` where:

- each column name is mapped to an attribute that stored as `key` in the map
- and the value of the column is stored as `value` in the map associated to the column `key`

In another word (shorter version):

- table column names => map keys
- table column values => map values

Well in Java, it would be something like:

```
@Entity(name="TABLE_1")
public class View extends HashMap<String, Object> {
    // no attributes here because the columns will be mapped as key of this class

    // and the value type here is Object because the type of the columns can be anything (i.e. varchar, integer, timestamp etc.)
}
```

I know this is not a typical kind of ORM mapping, and it is probably not the purpose of JPA at all. But it is the first thing come out of my mind in our use case.

### Use case

We have a relational database with a cup of tables and we also have a few views defined based on these tables. What we are trying to do right now is to develop a web based UI to work with the views defined in the database.

The more or less 'tricky' thing here is that the definition of the view are not completed yet, and we will certainly need to modify and/or add more views in the future. But the business requirement remains the same: allow user to query, filter and edit the views and eventually to perform other actions (like audit, add comments for example).

In this case, we need to be able to add/remove views to/from the application via configuration and use a common approach to handle a set of actions usable on different views. And part of the solution is to use a common container to hold data that blurs out "what a view really is". From where comes the idea to use a `java.util.Map`.

The reason I'm looking for using JPA mappings in our use case is the ability to use a more code-friendly criteria API, type conversion and avoid to use low level JDBC codes which are probably hard to maintain.

### Helps needed

Any answer of my question and other suggestions to the approach to be used in our use case are both appreciated.

### [Edited] Solution (with Alan Hay's suggestion)

Use Hibernate's **[Dynamic models](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch04.html#persistent-classes-dynamicmodels)** feature, I can easily do something like the following:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <!-- Specify the 'entity-name' instead of 'class' here to activate the dynamic model -->
    <class entity-name="DynamicEntity" table="TABLE1">
        <id name="id" column="COL_ID" type="long" />
        <property name="attribute1" column="COL_1" type="string" />
        <property name="attribute2" column="COL_2" type="string" />
        <property name="attribute3" column="COL_3" type="date" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Then everything is handled smoothly by Hibernate:

```
Session hibernateSession = ...;
Map dynamicEntity = (Map) hibernateSession.get("DynamicEntity", 1L);
System.out.println(dynamicEntity.getClass());
System.out.println(dynamicEntity);

// output
// class java.util.HashMap
// {$type$=DynamicEntity, id=1, attribute1=foo, attribute2=bar, attribute3=2013-11-19}
```

Comment: For the most part we try to use JPA but ever now and again we have to dip into Hibernate.  I remember reading about `@CollectionOfElements`.  I am not 100% sure but I think you could use that to do what you want to do.

Comment: If Hibernate could work have a look at this: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-mapping

Comment: Thx to mention it, @CollectionOfElements is definitely useful for mapping a collection of entities by taking some entity's attribute as the key. But it is not I'm looking for as mentioned. What I need is to use a Map as the entity, meaning the map key acts as the entity attribute and map value stores the value of the entity attribute...

Comment: Well, if you want to save Objects, instead of a special field, it starts to go beyond the scope of JPA. Of course you could try a schema with a `@Lob byte[] myObject;` (the serialized generic Object) but I think it is simply complicated. Besides, I wouldn't extend a HashMap, and rather include one (it could help you map it easier to the database). And of course, I think use clear that you loose the type safety here (you cannot say if an Object is a String or Integer).

Comment: I agree that the given sample isn't a 'nice' code example. It's just because I don't know how to express my needs in other form, it's just a sample of idea :) Well what I need is not to store pure Objects, but again, it is to have the possibility to use a Map as an entity mapped from a relational table where <table column names => map keys, table column values => map values>.

Comment: This sounds like a really bad idea. I worked on a system that was heavily map based but we migrated to JPA precisely to get away from this architecture. I can't tell you how bad the old map system was.

Comment: Glad to hear from different voices :) I don't like the idea very much neither, but yet I didn't find any other solution for our use case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. There is nothing in the JPA spec however if you are using Hibernate then the Hibernate 'Dynamic Models' feature seems to be exactly what you are looking for:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/persistent-classes-dynamicmodels.html

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that with the `java.util.Map` as it is only an interface. Also with a `HashMap` you cannot do it, as it does not have an ID column (beside other problems). But you can create an entity `MapEntity` that contains a `private Map internalMap;` and that implements the `Map` interface, manipulating the contained `internalMap` in each of the `Map`'s interface, obtaining a similar result. With this idea I don't know what the consequences are, when the `MapEntity` is used in other entities, but probably you shouldn't get any problems.

Example (View is in this case an `@Embeddable`. If View is an entity, use the [@MapKey](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapKey.html) annotation

```
public class MapEntity implements Map<Integer, View> {


    //add the id column...


    @ElementCollection//+other mapping configuration like @CollectionTable (name = "ViewMap", joinColumns = @JoinColumn (name = "view_id"))
    private Map<Integer, View> internalMap = new HashMap<Integer, View>;


    //implementation of a method from the Map interface. The other methods are simply delegated to the internalmap.
    @Override
    public View put(Integer key, View value) {
      internalMap.put(key, value);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thx Andrei. Yep I know I can't do it with `java.util.Map` directly, that's why I filed a sample with `java.util.HashMap` for example. Could you please be more precise about how to do the mappings with a concrete `java.util.Map` implementation class?

Comment: Added an example, where the View is an @Embeddable (or you can play with `@MapKey` if `View` is an entity). Of course, this is only an idea. Also added explanations about HashMap.

Comment: The problem still is how to map the View class mentioned in your provided example. I edited my post and added a Java sample about what I need. Thx again.